# Como formatear fecha

Tags: c#

Me gustaría arreglar la fecha a la hora de pasar los datos, lo que yo recibo es esto 20210505, me gustaría tener 05052021.

```csharp
  string fec = lista[0].FechaCont;
  string cadenaInvert = "";
  
  foreach (char letra in fec)
    {
     //Anteponer la letra a la cadena invertida
     cadenaInvert = letra + cadenaInvert;
    }

  linFin.FechaCont = cadenaInvert;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no me complicaría la vida, y haría uso de las conversiones que tiene `DateTime`, parseando tu fecha de entrada a `DateTime` usando [`ParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) (o [`TryParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) para mayor seguridad) y después convertirlo al formato deseado con `ToString`.

Sería algo así:

```
var fechaEntrada = "20210505";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var fechaDatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "yyyyMMdd", provider);
var fechasalida = fechaDatetime.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
// En fechasalida tendremos "05052021"
```

Debes tener en cuenta que debes añadir el namespace `System.Globalization`